# Is there a method to serialize a machine learning model in within tidymodels (similar to pickling a model in Python)?

Tags: pickle, tidymodels

I am aware that the in Python you can serialize a ML model using the [pickle module](https://www.educba.com/python-pickle/); however, is there a method to do something similar in the tidymodel space? My goal would be to be able to save a trained model to be deployed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, you can use `saveRDS` & `readRDS` to save/load any R object, just like Python's `pickle`. Those functions are not specific to Tidymodels, they are basic R functions that can be used to serialize any object.

**Usage**

```
saveRDS(any_r_object, "filename.rds")  
object_name <- readRDS("filename.rds")
```

There is also the `save()` & `load()` functions, they serve the same function are are mostly similar to `saveRDS()` & `readRDS()`. There are many online discussions/blogs comparing the two approaches.

Comment: `saveRDS` helped me save my model, but `loadRDS` was not a viable function for me. Instead, I substituted `readRDS` in place of `loadRDS` and that worked for me

Comment: Ahh yeah. It's `readRDS()` & not `loadRDS()`, I will update the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following up after a good while:

Some model fits in R, e.g. those fitted with the `"xgboost"` or `"keras"` engine in tidymodels, require native serialization methods to be saved and reloaded in a new R session properly. `saveRDS` and `readRDS` will do the trick most of the time, though [fall short](https://github.com/rstudio/bundle) for model objects from packages that require native serialization.

The folks from the tidymodels team put together a new package, [bundle](https://github.com/rstudio/bundle), to provide a consistent interface for native serialization of model objects. The `bundle()` verb prepares a model object for serialization, and then you can safely `saveRDS()` + `readRDS()` and pass between R sessions as you wish, and then `unbundle()` in the new session:

```
mod_bundle <- bundle(mod)
saveRDS(mod_bundle, file = "path/to/file.rds")

# in a new R session:
mod_bundle <- readRDS("path/to/file.rds")
mod_new <- unbundle(mod_bundle)
```